# About Progress bar in php

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

Sir i have created progress bar by using CSS and it works properly but i have to fix the stating and ending time of the progress bar. i will give the static value as end time and present time as starting time it should start from 0% and completes at 100%. But now i am using present time and i use if condition that progress bar should be 0% until it starts and the progress bar started directly jumps to 50% or 70% as per the ending time. so please help me as per this after starting the progress bar should starts from 0%.thank you i used the code as follows.....

```
$total = $t_time_seconds;
$current = $s_time_seconds;
$percent = round(($current/$total)*100,1);
$remain = $total - $current;
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: what is the condition for `0%`??

Comment: if(date("H:i:s", time())<="18:00:00")
{
 $percent=0;
}

Comment: this is code for 100 % and for 0% here follows

Comment: if(date("H:i:s", time())>="11:00:00")
{
 $percent=100;
}

Comment: your condition is like < than 6pm percent is 0 and > than 11am percent is all. what if the value is 10am??

Comment: $total = $t_time_seconds;
$current = $s_time_seconds;
$percent = round(($current/$total)*100,1);

Comment: please explain in brief what you want, im getting confused.

Comment: for the rest of the thing i am using this code sir but when the time crosses 6pm progress bar jumps to 50%+ but actually it should start from 0 then 2 then 4 like that

Comment: i need is when the time is 18:10:00 the progress bar must be 10% like that but as per my code given it starts from 54%

Comment: if time is 6pm, it shud give 10%??

Comment: s sir if it was 7 pm 20% and 8pm 30% like that

Comment: 11:00:00 is the ending time

Comment: it means 6pm of today to 11 am of tomorrow??

Comment: s sir that is i am asking

Comment: sorry for the late reply

Comment: what sir did u leaved me not telling any thing haa..............................

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to have a progress bar without adding some code [PACE](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/) can be an awesome tool for you.

Just include pace.js and a CSS theme of your choice, and you get a beautiful progress indicator for your page load and AJAX navigation.
Best thing with PACE is the auto detection of progress.

It contains various themes and color schemes as well.

Worth a try.

Comment: i want to fix starting and ending positions sir